# Profiler is telling me that comparison to nil is slow

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, profiling

I have a method which checks an `NSData`'s value as follows:

```
if (data == nil) {

//Method

}
```

But despite all of the stuff inside the method, it turns out that over 80% of the time is spent on the first line, checking if `data` is equal to `nil`. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Where does the variable get set? I think we need to see more code.

Comment: Is it possible the stuff inside is executed only at 1% of the runs because data is mostly nil so even if it takes longer time, it is almost never executed and takes less total time?

Comment: @Dani, +1. @Andrew, I can assure you that comparing a pointer against `nil` is not expensive. Either you're doing it a bazillion times (which means your problem lies elsewhere in whatever governs how often this is done) or your measurement is incorrect or misunderstood.

Comment: It's odd. I got rid of the nil thing, it still takes about the same amount of time (1 ms less) but now it's blaming another line. I'm doing this in instruments. Now i'm totally confused.

Comment: you need to show some screenshots of instruments

Comment: Performance instrumentation can be confusing.  Sampling of the instruction pointer will tend to occur at branch points, because that's where interrupts are checked, so at a fine granularity branches will often be "accused" of being responsible for all the time spent nearby.  Such sampling is really only valid over a fairly large block of code, not at an instruction-by-instruction level.

Comment: you're declaring a uiimage named as your nsdata? I always check (data.lenght) and it's very fast. By the way I think it's the whole block between {} that takes the time. and mainly the jpeg compression. put an nslog before and after your uiimagejpeg compression you will where the time is spent

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that profiling is done on the basis of "buckets", which have a resolution of so many bytes of code.  You usually can control this, but if you use "smaller" buckets you must have more of them to cover the same code.  If bucket size is, say, 100 bytes then profiling resolution will only be to within maybe a half-dozen lines.

Comment: but where are you getting "it is slow" from? Nothing in that screenshot says that.

Comment: The mistake is in believing that the 97% notation on the `if` applies only to one statement, when, in fact, it applies to all the statements down to the next highlighted line.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a direct comparison to `nil`. It's multiple statements on one line.

One way to divide the problem is to divide the statements. You can also step into your implementations. In short the profiler's highlighting is being misinterpreted.

Breaking this up:

```
NSData * thumbnailData = self.thumbnail;
NSUInteger length = thumbnailData.length;
```

Accessing a property does not take much time.

Accessing the length should not take much time (assuming this is immutable data).

I suspect there may be some lazy loading going on in `self.thumbnail`. However, the profiler will give you more detail if you drill down into the implementations.

The final point is that that may be interpreted local to the method. If that method is not a hotspot and those above methods really do no work, that just usually means "the thumbnail's usually loaded when you call this method".

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no faster way to check than a direct comparison with `nil`, or at least you won't gain any significant performance by fiddling with that line--this profiling data is inaccurate.

In my experience, this sort of behavior (Instruments 'blaming' the first line of a method incorrectly) occurs when the method (`-getThumbnail` in your case) is being run too many times. Try optimizing when `-getThumbnail` is called.

Comment: i don't see anything to suggest Instruments is blaming anything incorrectly.

Comment: OP said that changing the comparison in a trivial way resulted in a different line being blamed.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to think about how the classical sampling-type performance profiler works.

Basically while your program is running a timer goes off, say, every 100 microseconds, and your program is interrupted.  The profiler then examines the instruction pointer and, based on its value relative to the start and end of the code segment being profiled, indexes into an array of integer counters and increments the counter corresponding to the code address.

But there are (at least) three things that prevent this from being "perfect":

1. Except for very small programs it's impractical to have one counter for each instruction, so the code space is chopped up into intervals of, say, 16 bytes, or maybe 1000 bytes, depending on how you set it up, and an individual counter collects increments for all instructions in that range.  This means that the "precision" of the measurement with regard to exactly where you are in the program is less than perfect.
2. It depends a lot on the specific processor, but generally processors only recognize timer interrupts at certain points in the code, such as taken branches and when certain "system" operations are performed, or it may simply wait until the prefetch cache is drained.  So the profiler's timer interrupt may "fire", and the processor may continue executing for several more instructions.
3. Certain code sequences (such as a compare-and-swap) may disable interrupts, and so all activity within the disabled region will end up being "blamed" on the immediately following instruction.  Similarly, some sorts of system calls are made in a way that leaves interrupts disabled for the duration of the call, so again, the entire cost of the call is "blamed" on the immediately following instruction.